# Save generated image to model AND upload to S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I cannot find documentation on how to do what I need to do. My goal(s):

- User fills out a form with basic info
- Server-side a qr code is generated for that user.
- This qr code image needs to be uploaded to S3 to not bog down the server storage.
- This needs to be referenced in a model. WHY? This image will need to be displayed later in various front-end frameworks so at least the URL should be somewhere.

It is stated lower but note: the s3 upload IS functional via form in admin.

Currently I am building this out as an API to be used by various front-end frameworks so no forms in django will be used. All code is in testing mode so there is currently no security (just FYI). I am just trying to get this functionality working.

Current model:

```
from django.db import models

# Customer model only 
class Customers(models.Model):
    customerId = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    qr = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')           #THIS IS WHERE IT WOULD BE STORED
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    displayTag = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Views.py that is doing the saving

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse as j
from qrewards_api_pj.helper import generate_id, generate_qr
from django.core import serializers
from qrewards_api_pj.auto_responses import *
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import Customers
import qrcode

# serialized_queryset = serializers.serialize('json', some_queryset) - to be used later.
# Customer Actions Only

@csrf_exempt
def create_customer(request):
    if not request.method=="POST":
        return j(method_not_allowed, status=400)
    id = generate_id()
    qr = generate_qr(id, 'c')
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password'] # change to have hashing after testing
    phone = request.POST['phone']
    display_tag = request.POST['display_tag']
    Customers.objects.create(customerId=id, qr=qr.save(id+'.png'), email=email, password=password, phone=phone, displayTag=display_tag)
    return j(customer_created_success, status=200)
```

helper.py file that holds the helper function used to create qr and id

```
# id generator
from random import randint
import qrcode

def generate_id():
    chars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e' 'f' 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '!', '@', '#', '$', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=', '+', '[', ']', '{', '}', ';', '?', ]
    id = ''
    for i in range (0, 25):
        id =  id + chars[randint(0, len(chars)-1)]
    return id


# qr code generator
def generate_qr(type, id):
    # type will be a single char to append to the beginning of the id so that it can be determined if it is customer, award, business or other just be accessing the first character of the string. Unknown exactly what use this might have but it might come in handy later. 
    data = f'{type}{id}'
    return qrcode.make(data) # unsure what this will do.
```

Settings.py - for the S3 config (currently working when uploading images via admin panel)

```
"""
Django settings for qrewards_api_pj project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'HIDDEN HERE'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'qrewards_api_main',
    'customer_side',
    'business_side',
    'storages', 
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'qrewards_api_pj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'qrewards_api_pj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/


# AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'qrewards-images.s3.amazonaws.com'


# AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# ]

# STATIC_URL = 'https://qrewards-images.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'HIDDEN HERE'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'HIDDEN'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'HIDDEN'
AWS_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_VERITY = True
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
# STORAGES = {"default": {"BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"}}
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

With the code above the file is created and is stored in the project directory:[Image Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN2Cy.png)

The desire would be for this image to end up in my S3 bucket instead.

Comment: You can create a custom storage that saves to s3. But there are already a lot of solutions, I recommend you to check: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html
And its examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to make a few changes:

1. **QR Code Storage**: As per your requirement, you're generating the QR code on the fly and then saving it. If you're saving it directly to S3, there's no need to save it on your local server first. You can save it directly to S3.
2. **Model Changes**: Update the QR Field to ensure that it's ready to store an image link.
3. **Upload Logic**: Once the QR code is generated, instead of saving it to a local path, you can save it directly to your S3 bucket using Django's file storage API.

Here are the steps to achieve this:

**1. Model Changes**:

Change the QR field from `FileField` to `ImageField`:

```py
qr = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes/')
```

**2. Upload Logic**:

In the `create_customer` function, after generating the QR code, instead of saving it directly using the `save` method of the QR code object, we'll save it to the model's field so that it gets uploaded to S3.

Here's how you can do that:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def create_customer(request):
    if not request.method == "POST":
        return j(method_not_allowed, status=400)
    id = generate_id()
    qr_image = generate_qr(id, 'c')
    
    # Convert the QR code to an in-memory binary stream.
    from io import BytesIO
    buffer = BytesIO()
    qr_image.save(buffer, format="PNG")

    # Create a Django InMemoryUploadedFile from the stream.
    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
    file_content = ContentFile(buffer.getvalue())

    # Create the customer and save the QR code to S3.
    customer = Customers(customerId=id, email=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password'], phone=request.POST['phone'], displayTag=request.POST['display_tag'])
    customer.qr.save(f"{id}.png", file_content)
    customer.save()

    return j(customer_created_success, status=200)
```

**3. S3 Configuration**:

Your S3 configuration in `settings.py` looks good since you're able to upload files via the admin panel. So, this approach should work just as effectively when you're using the API.

This approach will save the QR code directly to S3 without storing it locally on your server.

Comment: I don't know how much to thank you for this solution. It is a shame that after 3 years of doing python here and there I have never heard of BytesIO and what it does. It is also a shame that after 2 years with django projects I have never used ContentFile. I clearly need to explore django and python useful libraries like this. Thank you very much for your help!!